# EventBus 3.0 registerSticky deprecated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, event-bus

Cannot resolve method registerSticky(this) in place of register(this)

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

I have tried 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0' and 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0-beta1' in my Gradle. No idea why this method is not appearing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's seem `registerSticky` are deprecated and removed. 
I think, you should register as normal event, then use `postSticky` method

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    //...
}
```

Please refer: http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/

Comment: That didn't do anything. I also looked up on gradle please a different library I saw on a github project 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0-beta1' instead of 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'. Still no registerSticky() method!

Comment: @VictorBoutte': i understood your question. It's seem `registerSticky` are deprecated and removed. I think, you should register as normal event, then use `postSticky` method
Refer:
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/

Comment: Yes exactly! If you can edit your answer to reflect this, I'll accept it. Thanks mate